# Execute different operations of a NN model graph with different hardware accelerators while using Onnxruntime

Tags: android, onnxruntime, nnapi

I was trying to utilize NNAPI via OnnxRuntime for NN model inferencing on an Android device. Based on the youtube video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij5MoUnLQ0E it is possible to specify the hardware accelerators for operators in the model. Any guidance on how to proceed with that would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In NNAPI, it is possible to discover which hardware accelerators are present, and to select specific ones for running a model.

If the application specifies more than one accelerator, the NNAPI runtime partitions the work depending on the characteristics of each accelerator and the layers they support.

It is not possible for a program to make that decision on a layer by layer basis. If that's what you need, you may have to break down your model into sub-models.

See the [Device discovery and assignment](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/neuralnetworks#discovery-assignment) section in the NNAPI documentation for more details.

I am not familiar with OnnxRuntime. I don't know if this package exposes that functionality.